# Помогите Разделить XML на определенные узлы

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Есть XML строка. Не могу ни как понять как получить только содержимое узла  ,а затем разбить на на отдельных Person.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetJob xmlns="http:// ">
            <GetResult>
                <Result>00</Result>
                <Data>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Ивано Иван Иванович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Петров Петр Петрович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
                </Data>
            </GetResult>
        </<GetJob >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Пробовал что то типа

```
  XElement contacts = XElement.Parse();
contacts.Element(Element("GetJob ").Element("GetResult")
В итоге хотел бы получить что то типа 

> `                    <Person>
                        <Name>Петров Петр Петрович</Name>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                    </Person>
`
```

Comment: Нужно учитывать пространства имён.

Comment: Принимая во внимание soap, предположу, что этот xml получен из какого-то сервиса. По идее, сервис должен предоставлять описание WSDL. По нему следует сгенерировать набор классов и работать через них.

Comment: Я уже ответил на ваш вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77585453/divide-xml-into-specific-nodes